# How do I override passport authentication when unit testing using mocha/chai?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I tried setting `app.request.isAuthenticated = function(){return true;}` as was recommended in another answer but this didn't work for me.

This is the authenticate method that I use as middleware on the routes that I want authenticated:

```
const authenticate = [passport.authenticate(['bearer'], {session: false}), (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
        return next(null);
    }
    else {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    }
}];
```

A typical secured call would look like this

```
router.get('/securedInfo', authenticate, function(req,res,next){
    // do stuff
});
```

I'd also prefer not to authenticate in this test because I'd like to separate testing my RESTful API tests from my authentication logic (because the latter will most likely change over time).